# When I try to access an element in an array of objects, it writes to all elements at once

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a nested object with arrays in it and I also have an array of that object. When I try to access to the first element of that object, I see that all the elements of the array are written. How can I fix it?
My code is like this (my original code was using "for" loops but I wanted to simplyfy to see what's wrong)

```
level = Array(heroStatus.length); 
  name = Array(heroStatus.length);
  levelnum = Array(heroStatus.length);
  equipped = Array(heroStatus.length);
  inInventory = Array.from(Array(5), () => new Array(heroStatus.length));

  equipmentType = {level,name,levelnum,equipped,inInventory};
  let equipment = Array.from(Array(6), () => equipmentType );
  
  i = 0;
  equipment[0].level = heroStatus.map((x) =>  x[2+(2*i)]);
  equipment[0].name = heroStatus.map((x) =>  x[3+(2*i)]);
  equipment[0].levelNum = equipment[0].level.map((x) => equipmentLevelNames.findIndex((y)=> y==x ));
  equipment[0].equipped = heroEquippedItems.map((x) =>  x[i]);
  equipment[0].inInventory[0] = equipment[0].level.map((x)=> inventoryItemList.findIndex(y => y[1] ==        equipment[0].name[equipment[0].level.indexOf(x)] && y[0] == equipment[0].level[equipment[0].level.indexOf(x)]));
  equipment[0].inInventory[0] = equipment[0].inInventory[0].map((x)=> {if(x ==-1){ return false}else{ return  true} });
  
  i = 1;
  equipment[1].level = heroStatus.map((x) =>  x[2+(2*i)]);
  equipment[1].name = heroStatus.map((x) =>  x[3+(2*i)]);
  equipment[1].levelNum = equipment[1].level.map((x) => equipmentLevelNames.findIndex((y)=> y==x ));
  equipment[1].equipped = heroEquippedItems.map((x) =>  x[i]);
  equipment[1].inInventory[0] = equipment[1].level.map((x)=> inventoryItemList.findIndex(y => y[1] == equipment[1].name[equipment[1].level.indexOf(x)] && y[0] == equipment[1].level[equipment[1].level.indexOf(x)]));
  equipment[1].inInventory[0] = equipment[1].inInventory[0].map((x)=> {if(x ==-1){ return false}else{ return  true} });
 
  i = 2;
  equipment[2].level = heroStatus.map((x) =>  x[2+(2*i)]);
  equipment[2].name = heroStatus.map((x) =>  x[3+(2*i)]);
  equipment[2].levelNum = equipment[2].level.map((x) => equipmentLevelNames.findIndex((y)=> y==x ));
  equipment[2].equipped = heroEquippedItems.map((x) =>  x[i]);
  equipment[2].inInventory[0] = equipment[2].level.map((x)=> inventoryItemList.findIndex(y => y[1] == equipment[2].name[equipment[2].level.indexOf(x)] && y[0] == equipment[2].level[equipment[2].level.indexOf(x)]));
  equipment[2].inInventory[0] = equipment[2].inInventory[0].map((x)=> {if(x ==-1){ return false}else{ return  true} });
```

Here is the nested structure of the object:
[image]

And here is what I see just before the line that starts with "i=1". My test code doesn't even go up to index 5
[image]

Initially I wanted to write to every element in an array of objects in a for loop. When I saw that every element has the same value which is the values of the last element of the array, I wanted to see it more clearly and removed the "for loop". I also tried using .push() method but it also pushed the calculated object to all the objects in the array of objects.

Comment: `Array.from(Array(6), () => equipmentType )` makes an array where each of the 6 elements contains a reference to the **exact same object**.

Comment: A lot of your code suffers from the same problem: when you re-use an object (or an array) the way your code does, all of the uses point to exactly the same (single) thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not making copies of the nested arrays and objects when you create the `equipment` array. So all your elements are references to the same arrays.

Change

```
let equipment = Array.from(Array(6), () => equipmentType );
```

to

```
let equipment = Array.from(Array(6), () => {
  let level = Array(heroStatus.length),
    name = Array(heroStatus.length),
    levelnum = Array(heroStatus.length),
    equipped = Array(heroStatus.length),
    inInventory = Array.from(Array(5), () => new Array(heroStatus.length));
  return {level, name, levelnum, equipped, inInventory};
});
```

and repeat it for all the other similar codes.

Your code puts the same obj